# Constructing a time evolution operator $e^{it H}$ for $H^2=I$

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, hamiltonian-simulation

**Consider a Hamiltonian $H = \sigma_x \otimes \sigma_z$
Construct the time evolution operator $U(t) = \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{iHt}{\frac{h}{2\pi}}}$ [Hint:Write down the expansion of $\mathrm{e}^x$ and use the property of $H^2$]**

This was one of my assignment problems and I really couldn't make sense of what the hint implied and ended up getting $H^2 = I$ and don't really know how and where to use this.

Comment: You are correct that $H^2 = I$. Have you written down the expansion of the matrix exponential and plugged in $H$? What do you get?

Comment: Have you done anything similar in class with, for example $\sigma_x$ or $\sigma_z$?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint:

You are correct that $H^2 = I$. Let's set $a:=\frac{-2it\pi}{h}$ for simplicity. Then the definition of the matrix exponential gives us

$$U(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!}H^n$$

Can you use $H^2 = I$ to help evaluate this?

Answer (score 1):

The exponential of an operator is defined with respect to its series expansion. The fact that $H^2=I$ will simplify this expansion greatly.